# How to solve Google AutoML error: The target column can not contain invalid value for regression

Tags: regression, google-cloud-automl, automl

I am trying to do AutoML training for binary-regression on a column with just 2 possible values:

[image]

As you can see, it's just either "up" or "down", there is no null or missing value.  Seems simple enough but I am getting this error:

```
Error Messages: The target column nextday_direction can not contain invalid value for regression.
```

What invalid value is it talking about?  Does Google regression training have to be 0 or 1?  No distinct value allowed?

Here is my training settings:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you should change the `Objective` - it should be classification. You can also try MLJAR AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised - it will detect the machine learning task automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it is indeed have to be numeric, distinct value doesn't work, changed up/down to 0/1 and it works fine.